# How the flex box item use the full width of its parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=item>Box 1</div>
  <div class=item>Box 2</div>
  <div class=item>Box 3</div>
  <div class=item>Box 4</div>
  <div class=item>Box 5</div>
</div>
```

My question, how can "Box 1", "Box 2", "Box 3" use the full width of the "container" class? and "Box 4" and "Box 5" will line up from below to the above box "Box 1" and "Box 2".

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you just asking why the first three boxes are on one line and the other two are on the second?

Comment: No, I want the first three boxes to use the full width of its parent, instead of leaving space on the right side of "Box 3".  The other two will still have to vertical align to the above two boxes (Box 1 and Box 2)

Comment: change their width to 33.3333% (and add box-sizing) instead of 70px?

Comment: I'm thinking of using the "justify-content: space-between" inside the "container" class but it still not correct.

Comment: As Pete suggested, why not add `flex: 1 1 33.3333%` to `.item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually kind of a brainteaser until I realized you need CSS grid instead of Flexbox :). There doesn't seem to exist a solution with Flexbox without adding "ghost divs", which isn't really a good option.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 110px 110px 110px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=item>Box 1</div>
  <div class=item>Box 2</div>
  <div class=item>Box 3</div>
  <div class=item>Box 4</div>
  <div class=item>Box 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several ways to go about it; here are two ways:

Use `flex-grow`. If you add `flex-grow: 1` to the `item` selector then the boxes on each row will take up the full width of the container. Note: With this solution you may want to make sure you have the same number of boxes per row, if you want these boxes to appear as a uniform grid. Otherwise the line with only one or two boxes will be stretched to fill the width of the container. So keep that in mind.

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 70px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Second option: Add `margin: 0 auto;` to the `item` selector, and they will fill the width by centering.

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, we could also use `flex-basis: 100%` instead of `flex-grow: 1`.